# How to limit an array with 10,000 objects thats linked to my angular ui-select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have an array with 10,000 objects in it and its crashing the browser every time I click on the select. Is there anyway to limit the `ui-select` to only show 10 on the screen at a time? Additionally, the library I am using is [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki).

```
 <ui-select ng-model="ed.main.user.UserID.selected" theme="bootstrap">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="{{main.editTicket.UserDisplayName}}">
         {{$select.selected.DisplayName}}
     </ui-select-match>
     <ui-select-choices repeat="t in main.users |filter:$select.search"value="{{$selected.UserID}}">
         <div ng-bind-html="t.DisplayName | highlight: $select.search"></div>
         <small ng-bind-html="t.UserID | highlight: $select.search"></small>
     </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

Comment: 1st thing the you should not bind 10,000 objects to your `ui-select`, it may hangs you browser..you should those options lazily as user types an input

Comment: this is not an angular ui bootstrap question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) e.g...

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="o as o for o in items | limitTo: 10"></select>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qxydfg9k/) - demo

---

Per your update, modify your `repeat` as such

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="t in main.users | filter:$select.search | limitTo: 10"value="{{$selected.UserID}}">
    <div ng-bind-html="t.DisplayName | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small ng-bind-html="t.UserID | highlight: $select.search"></small>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using ui-select repeat and tried the above example but it still crashes the browser when I click on the select. I'll add my code.

Comment: @Rethabile I attempted to update my answer for your situation. Could you check it out?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the angular ui-select, but doesn't it implement something like infinite scroll paging or similar?

Comment: @Juri unsure, I was checking out the [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) docs and couldn't see anything apparent

Answer (score 1):

Her is my solution which lets you replenish new items on scroll. Also works for filtered lists that may be too big.

```
       <ui-select-choices 
         position="up" 
         all-choices="ctrl.allTenThousandItems"  
         refresh-delay="0"
         repeat="person in $select.pageOptions.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search} ">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
         email: {{person.email}}
         age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
       </small>
   </ui-select-choices>
```

[Detailed Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077388/2103767)

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xtpV5G?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use only `limitTo:itemsPerPage`  in html. 
Change limitTo value dynamically by using $timeout function.
call `addMoreChoices()` from where you want to load more options.

```
 addMoreChoices();
function addMoreChoices(){
            if($scope.itemsPerPage<$scope.List.length){
                $scope.itemsPerPage += 100;
                $timeout(addMoreChoices, 100);
            }
        }
```